# Android - gridView onItemClick

Tags: android, gridview

Hi i have strange problem with my gridView. I set on this itemClikListener and it doesn't work.
Structure of view is this: `GridView -> LinearView with ImageView`.

When i set itemClickListener as below it doesn't work:

```
    GridView board;
    board.setAdapter(boardAdapter);

    board.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("CLICK", "onClick");
        }
    });
```

This is't working, my console is clear.

When I implement listener on each of imageView (on each item of gridView) separatly in my `GridViewAdapter -> boardAdapter` everything works fine.

Fragment of working code in `Adapter getView()`

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("CLICK", "onClick");
            }
        });
```

Why I can't appy the listener to whole gridView and their items? I need have this listeners in class that have fields gridView, and gridViewAdapter, not in gridViewAdapter?

I searched in stackoverflow but i can't make it. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem in you code is missing @Override annotation.

```
board.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int     position, long id) {
        Log.d("CLICK", "onClick");
    }
});
```

If still that doesn't works. Then may be any of your Grid Item's child view is also listening for click event.
If you know about the even handling procedure of android Touch Framework then you probably understand my point. Else It will be very good to know how android Touch Framework works.
You can Learn about that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYoN-OvdZ3M&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD&index=19).

Comment: You have right!
i totally forget about >clickable annotation in linearLayout which contains imageView.

Thank for help. You gave me i nice lesson, thanks for this point of view.

Answer (score 1):

`@Override` annotation is missing for implemented method. Also anonymous inner class should refer from AdapterView. Please see below sample code.

```
board.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("CLICK", "onClick");
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry, I add this annotation and nothing changed

Comment: @MaciejWójcik The anonymous inner class should be `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` instead of `new OnItemClickListener()`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these to your **`GridView` Items's** `layout.xml`

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Also make sure that your Adapter returns `true` for the method

```
isEnabled(int position)
```