# fragment setOnTouchListener not triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I have the following kotlin code, and I can't get the onTouch\click listener called.
I am using an emulator and i click the fragment many times in many places and nothing seem to get the listeners called. I put breakpoints and print\logs and get nothing...

The gridview has an onItemClick. if I remove the gridview - the touch listener works, but I do need the gridview and onItemClick. So how do I combine both?

fragment xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    tools:context=".fragments.MainAppFragment">

        <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/my_grid_view"
        android:horizontalSpacing="15dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="15dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment class:

```
    class MainAppFragment : Fragment(){

        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
          val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_app, container, false)

          view.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("TAG", "onTouch entered");
          }
          view.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            print(event.action)
            true
          }

          return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you're setting your click listener on the `FrameLayout` but the clicks are actually dispatched to the `GridView` since it's covering the whole dimension of your root view (`FrameLayout`).

You can either

1. Decrease the dimension of your `GridView` for the events to be dispatched to your root layout.
2. Set your click listeners on `GridView` where the events are actually happening.

Comment: Do i need to decrease the dimensions of the grid view just a little? or for the clicks to actually be outside of the gridview?

Comment: Decreasing the dimension causes the clicks **outside** of `GridView` be dispatched to `FrameLayout` but the clicks that happen inside `GridView` will still be dispatched to the grid itself. If you're actually meaning to catch the clicks on the grid, the second option would be the right choice.

Comment: I tried the following and it did not work either gridView?.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            Log.d("asd", "asd");
            true}

Comment: setontouchlistener on the gridview doesn't work either

Comment: I can see that if I delete the gridview, the listeners work but I do need the gridview, so I'll appreciate help on setting the ontouchlistener correctly on the gridview. I should also mention my gridview has an onItemClick

Comment: `GridView`s are designed in a way to pass click events of each item to a different listener which is `setOnItemClickListener`. You can read more about it and its use cases [here in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42398904/4399414).

Comment: Sorry I dont understand how to solve this issue. I have an on item click in order to handle clicks on items in the gridview and i want to add an oneventlistener in order to count clicks on the screen (anywhere other than on the items) how do you suggest to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Do to initiate variable for the gridview finding it's I'd
Then do a setOnClickListener for that variable and return the view..